# Can see the nautilus menu in Desktop when using Gnome Shell

Tags: nautilus, gnome

when I update my system several weeks ago, I started to see the nautilus menu in my desktop! I saw this because I had a transparent Gnome Shell panel.

Today I re installed Ubuntu and things seems to be ok. Then I installed a shell extension which will hide the top menu... When its hidden, I can again see the menu! Anyone know how to get rid of it?

Check the attached image... Its a gnome shell environment in Ubuntu. The top panel is hidden!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should do ONE of the following (the one that you prefer):

1) Set from Gnome Tweak Tool that the file manager should NOT handle the desktop (this will also get rid of the icons on the desktop)

2) Remove the packages `appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt`.

Comment: Will the second option remove the desktop icons?

Comment: No, it will not affect them :)

Answer (score 1):

Just found a fix for this without removing anything :D Check this : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11731822&posted=1#post11731822

Simply have to run this code and restart :

> echo '[ ${DESKTOP_SESSION#ubuntu} = $DESKTOP_SESSION ] && unset UBUNTU_MENUPROXY' | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntu-menu-proxy

@dadexix86 Thanks a lot for your answer mate.. it will also work!